# How to compare list of anonymous object with Enum in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I am forming List of object as below, Control is List of Enum.

Ex:

```
public enum Controls
        {
            Undefined = 0,
            [EnumReferenceTypeField(DisplayName = "Edit")]
            Edit = 1,

            [EnumReferenceTypeField(DisplayName = "Save")]
            Save = 2,
}
```

**Constructing actions List is already written code, am not allowed to change.**

```
 var actions = new List<object>();
                foreach (var control in Controls)
                {
                    actions.Add(new
                    {
                        c = (int)control ,
                        t = control.ToString()
                    });
                }
```

and checking the condition as below,

```
 if (actions.Exists(a => a == (object)Enums.Controls.Save))
  actions.Remove(Enums.Controls.Submit);
```

Even if i convert Enum to object type the Exists condition not satisfying,  even though actions list have Save action. If i mouse over action at runtime it has to values "2" and "Save". i want to check Save is exists and perform some logic.

Comment: you are comparing anonymous object with Enum object. they are never equal. maybe you want to compare enum with `a.c` ? you should use `dynamic` instead of `object`. or the better way is to create a custom class for this.

Comment: Control is list of Enum. But i need to form anonymous object because i need int value and string for UI validation

Comment: You don't **need** anonymous objects, you could create a class with two properties, the enum values and the enum names. This has been asked and answered many times here in SO.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, List of objects are not written by me, its already existing code. Now i need to check particular control is availble or not. That logic only i have to do. I cant change already existing code, based on that list many code logic are there. If i touch that, have to change lot of things.

Comment: maybe, what you really want for the lambda expression is `a => a.c == (int)Enums.Controls.Save`

Comment: `Controls` cannot be that enum. You cannot iterate a enum type like that.

Comment: your code doesn't make sense. Does Controls have a `Submit` value or not? What is `Enums`? Are you sure `Controls` is not a `List<ActionType>`? What happened to your `ActionType` type? How are you enumerating `Controls` if it is an enum type and not a list?

Comment: Controls list is formed based on few logic. Whenever some logic is satisfied, we are adding enum to the controls. Finally the list of objects are   passed to angularJS UI, which expects int number and string value of control(1, Save). Now i need to write conditon to remove some control from list of objects before sending it to UI.

Comment: I have a feeling there is something important missing here, since it wouldn't make any sense to build a list of the *static* enum values and then check if one value is present and remove another value.

Comment: I cant post whole code here, which related to this list of objects, its around 600 hundred lines. The controls are added by some user. Now due to some security reason, i need to remove few controls based on user authenticity and if already some controls exist. Thing is that, am not allowed to change list of objects forming. If i can change the list of object type, its very easy to check. But i cant change that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After some analysis I have tried myself and below code is working perfectly.

Created anonymous object from enum like below,

```
 object saveAction= new 
            {
                c = (int)Enums.Controls.Save,
                t = Enums.Controls.Save.ToString()
            };
object submitAction = new
        {
             c = (int)Enums.Controls.Submit,
             t = Enums.Controls.Submit.ToString()
        };

if (actions.Exists(a => a.Equals(saveAction)))
              {
                  actions.Remove(submitAction);
              }
```

Equals only working not "==". Refer below link

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1237024&seqNum=4

Answer (score 3):

There are various things wrong here:

1. If `Controls` truly is an `enum` as you have shown, then you cannot enumerate it with

   ```
   foreach (var control in Controls) // won't work if Controls is an enum type
   ```

   You can instead use something like:

   ```
   var controls =
      Enum
      .GetValues(typeof(Controls))
      .Cast<Controls>()
      .ToList();

   foreach (var control in controls)
      ...
   ```
2. Since `actions` is a `List<object>`, and the items you are adding to it are of anonymous type, you cannot access the members of the items. Either `actions` must be implicitly typed:

   ```
   var actions =
      controls // as above
      .Select(control => new {
         c = (int)control ,
         t = control.ToString()
      }).ToList();
   ```

   or you need to use a non-anonymous type and cast to it:

   ```
   class MyAction {
      public int c { get; set; }
      public string t { get; set; }

      public MyAction(Controls control) {
         c = (int)control;
         t = control.ToString();
      }
   }

   var actions = new List<MyAction>();
   foreach (var control in controls)
      actions.Add(new MyAction(control));
   ```
3. If `Controls` is defined how you say, there is no such value as `Controls.Submit`.
4. If `Controls` really is an `enum`, then it does not make any sense to have a line like:

   ```
   if (actions.Exists(a => a == (object)Enums.Controls.Save))
   ```

   because the members of `Controls` are static and known at compile time. You should be able to reason about them yourself.

More than likely, the code you have posted is incomplete or incorrect in a critical way.

Comment: am not getting a.value. In if condition a does not have any "value" property.

Comment: I cant change forming of list of objects, its old code and based on that many logic are written. i need to write logic if some control exists then remove some control.

Comment: Am not getting a.c in intellisense, its not showing at all. in run time i could see action has, 2 values namely c=1 and t= save. but while coding, both c and t not available.

Comment: @Govind well, I guess that's because `actions` is a `List<object>`. It shouldn't even compile. You can't access members of an anonymous type without strong implicit typing. You need `var` and `ToList`, as above.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. so i created another anonymous object from Enum and checking the condition, its working now. I have posted this as answer. It might help someone. Thanks.